# SQL : delete using wildcard value with exceptions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to delete some rows where the JobNumber is like __10% (that's with two underscores) but **not** the values beginning CH10% or CG10%

This is the original SQL that is deleting the good data.

```
DELETE  FROM @TaskMaster
WHERE   JobNumber LIKE '__10%'
```

This is what I have:

```
DELETE  FROM @TaskMaster
where (select JobNumber from @TaskMaster where JobNumber NOT LIKE 'CH10%' or JobNumber NOT LIKE 'CG10%' ) like '__10%'
```

But get the error

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 140 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,> >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

any help is gratefully received
Pete

Comment: it is always advisable to use `PK` while using `delete` statements. could you try this solution `delete from @TaskMaster
where JobNumber like '__10%'
and JobNumber not like 'CH10%' 
and JobNumber not like 'CG10%';`

Comment: Nothing at all wrong with deleting without using PK. But you have the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just rearrange your where clause:

```
DELETE  FROM @TaskMaster
where JobNumber NOT LIKE 'CH10%' 
and JobNumber NOT LIKE 'CG10%'   
and JobNumber like '__10%'
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. Nothing like trying to over engineer a problem. This worked.

Answer (score 1):

The correct query to use would be this:

```
DELETE  FROM @TaskMaster
where JobNumber NOT LIKE 'CH10%' 
and JobNumber NOT LIKE'CG10%'   
and JobNumber LIKE'__10%'
```

Your query didn't work because it has a syntax error, any subquery should follow the format as below:

```
SELECT column-names
FROM table-name1
WHERE value IN (SELECT column-name
                FROM table-name2 
                WHERE condition)
```

In your case, you missing the `value` part of the `where` clause in the parent query. If you were to modify the existing query it would be something like this:

```
DELETE  FROM @TaskMaster
where JobNumber IN 
      (select JobNumber from @TaskMaster 
       where JobNumber NOT LIKE 'CH10%' OR
       JobNumber NOT LIKE 'CG10%') 
AND JobNumber LIKE '__10%'
```

But still, I would prefer using the above query and not this.